# Проблема связанный с сортировкой матрицы

Tags: c++

Вот мое задание я практически все пункты выполнил,но проблема у меня с сортировкой.Я написал функцию (Insertion Sort) для последнего пункта и когда я пытался вывести его он мне выводит не сортированную матрицу.

Написать перегруженные функции (int, double, char) для выполнения следующих задач:
- Инициализация квадратной матрицы;
- Вывод матрицы на экран;
- Определение максимального и минимального элемента на главной диагонали матрицы;
- Сортировка элементов по возрастанию отдельно для каждой строки матрицы.

Crandom.h

```
//Crandom.h(header file)
#ifndef __CRANDOM__
#define __CRANDOM__
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int random(int min, int max);
int random(int min, int max, unsigned int wheel);
void srandom(unsigned int value = 0);
#endif // __CRANDOM__
```

Crandom.cpp

```
//Crandom.cpp(я написал функцию для заполнение рандомных чисел матрицу)
#include"Crandom.h"
int random(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        swap(min, max);
    }
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

}
int random(int min, int max, unsigned int wheel)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        swap(min, max);
    }
    srand(wheel);
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

}
void srandom(unsigned int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(nullptr));
    }
    else
    {
        srand(value);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Crandom.h";
const int rows = 3, columns = 3;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
int matrix[rows][columns];


int fill_matrix(int matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = random(-64,64);
    }
    return 1;
}
int out_matrix(int matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 1;
}
int min_e_matrix(int matrix[rows][columns]) {
    min = matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min > matrix[i][i])
            min = matrix[i][i];
    }

    cout<<"Min element is == "<< min;
    return 1;
}
int max_e_matrix(int arr[rows][columns]) {
    min = matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min < matrix[i][i])
            min = matrix[i][i];
    }
    cout << "Max element is == " << min;
    return 1;
}
double fill_matrix(double matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = (double)(random(5, 16))/ (random(2, 9));
    }
    return 1;
}
double out_matrix(double matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 1;
}
double min_e_matrix(double matrix[rows][columns]) {
    min = (double)matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min > matrix[i][i])
            min = (double)matrix[i][i];
    }

    cout << "Min element  is == " << min;
    return 1;
}
double max_e_matrix(double arr[rows][columns]) {
    min = matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min < matrix[i][i])
            min = (double)matrix[i][i];
    }
    cout << "Max element is == " << min;
    return 1;
}
char fill_matrix(char matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = (double)random(1, 255);
    }
    return 1;
}
char out_matrix(char matrix[rows][columns]) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 1;
}
char min_e_matrix(char matrix[rows][columns]) {
    min = (double)matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min > matrix[i][i])
            min = (double)matrix[i][i];
    }

    cout << "Min element  is == " << min;
    return 1;
}
char max_e_matrix(char arr[rows][columns]) {
    min = matrix[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; ++i) {
        if (min < matrix[i][i])
            min = (double)matrix[i][i];
    }
    cout << "Max element is == " << min;
    return 1;
}

void array_print(int arr[rows][columns]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }cout << endl;
    }
}

void insertion_sort(int arr[rows][columns]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1])
            {
                int swap = arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1];
                arr[i][j - 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    fill_matrix(matrix);
    out_matrix(matrix);
    min_e_matrix(matrix);
    cout << "\n";
    max_e_matrix(matrix);
    cout << "\n";
    insertion_sort(matrix);
    array_print(matrix);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание требует написать функцию сортировки отдельно для каждой строки. Каждая строка матрицы, это одномерный массив, и вам нужно написать функцию сортировки для обычного массива, имеющий `columns` элементов:

```
//сортировка элементов матрицы, отдельно для каждой строки
void insertion_sort(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1])
            {
                int swap = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А потом, уже можете сортировать все строки матрицы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)         
    insertion_sort(matrix[i]);
```

Вами написанной функции вы пытаетесь сравнивать указатели: `arr[j] < arr[j - 1]` , поскольку у вас `arr` является двумерным массивом, и на основе этого сравнения вы меняете местами значения. Конечно такая программа будет вести себя совершенно не так(в данном случаи условие никогда не выолнится), как вы ожидали. В дальнейшем старайтесь не использовать глобальные обьекты, а передать в функции соответствующие обьекты(переменные)(в данном случаи, указатель и размер).  Это более  разумный подход...

Comment: Спасибо дружище за объяснение я понял свою ошибку,с этого момента я постараюсь передать в функции соответствующие объекты,а не использовать их как глобальные переменные.Доброго вам дня и ещё раз спасибо вам.